# Entity Framework and WCF (Returning Entities Attached To Context)

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have a WCF service that calls the following method in one of my Repository objects to create a new sale object in the database

```
public static Sale New(Sale sale)
{
    using (var ctx = new DBcontext())
    {
        ctx.Sales.AddObject(sale);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return sale;
    }
}
```

The WCF method calling this looks like this

```
public Sale SaleNew(Sale sale)
{
    return SaleRepository.New(sale);
}
```

When I call this from a client application I get the following error

*"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."*

If I step through all the code seems to run fine and the record gets insterted into the database. If I add the following line to my repository method after the SaveChanges it works fine

```
ctx.Detach(sale);
```

Is the exception happening because I'm disposing the context as soon as the method returns? Is using the entity context in this way bad practise ie disposing of it straight away? I'm only doing this because its SOA and pretty much stateless so all my repository methods create the context return the value and dispose the context. Anything that is passed in will either get added to the context or re-attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As advised I turned on tracing in WCF and watched what was happening. There was a proxy exception occurring. In this case as I'm using my own POCO objects I don't really want proxy objects so I set the ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled property in my DatabaseContext to false and it now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

1)  Is using the entity context in this way bad practise ie disposing of it straight away?

No, that's how I do it - and I believe it is the proper way of doing it. But creating context can be **expensive** and with EF we are stuck with **no ideal way** of reusing the context.

2) `ctx.Detach(sale);`

This as far as I know should not be required for what you are doing although I have had loads of issues with attaching and detaching when I reuse the same entities. *This should be only needed if you need to re-attach to context.* Are you using **Lazy-Loading**?

Comment: In this case I'm not using Lazy Loading but I probably will use it elsewhere in the future.

Comment: See where your context is getting referenced if you do not put the the detach. It is probably at the time of serialisation.

Comment: My entities are just POCO objects so should have no knowledge of the context. As far as I can see the context shouldn't be touched once the entity is returned from the repository method. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: Which version of EF and which approach are you using? EF entities do have knowledge of the context when you generate your entities from database.

Comment: I'm using EF4 CTP and am using POCO objects rather than the auto generated entity objects.

Comment: Did you try to use WCF tracing on your service? Did you explicitely turned off the Lazy loading? - it is turned on by default on DBContext.