# How can I force Unity App Block to load new Object instances in WCF?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using Unity Application Block to load my dependancies, a problem I am having is when all my dependancies are loaded it is behaving abnormally.

I have a service that takes a business interface using constructor injection, and that business interface takes a repository interface as constructor injection. The problem I have is when I load user details from the database the field values are always the same (even after I manually change them in the DB). Therefore I think it is because it is using the same instance EntityFramework context instance for each time the service is opened.

The only way I can get Entity Framework to load the correct details is to recycle IIS.

Is there a way I can force Unity to create new object instances for its dependancies and force them to be dispose when the WCF request has completed?
I have tried using the transient lifetime manager but this is not curing the problem.

**Code:**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private IUserAdmin _UserBusiness { get; set; }

    public UserService()
    {

    }

    [InjectionConstructor]
    public UserService(IUserAdmin userBusiness)
        : this()
    {
        this._UserBusiness = userBusiness;
    }
}

public class UserAdmin : BusinessBase, IUserAdmin
{
    private IRepository<DBUserAccount> _UserRepository { get; set; }

    [InjectionConstructor]
    public UserAdmin(IRepository<DBUserAccount> userRepository)
    {
        this._UserRepository = userRepository;
    }
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private Entities _Context;

    private ObjectSet<T> _ObjectSet;

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        this._Context = new Entities();
        this._ObjectSet = this._Context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }
}
```

Unity Config:

```
<register type="Services.Contracts.IUserService, Server.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= 683f160d975782be"
            mapTo="Services.Implementations.UserService, Server.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= 683f160d975782be">
    <lifetime type="transient"/>
  </register>
<register type="Server.Business.Users.IUserAdmin, Server.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= 683f160d975782be"
            mapTo="Server.Business.Users.UserAdmin, Server.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= 683f160d975782be">
    <lifetime type="transient"/>
  </register>
<register type="Server.DataLogic.IRepository`1[[Server.DataModels.DBUserAccount, Server.DataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= 683f160d975782be]], Server.DataLogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= 683f160d975782be"
            mapTo="Server.DataLogic.GenericRepository`1[[Server.DataModels.DBUserAccount, Server.DataModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= 683f160d975782be]], Server.DataLogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= 683f160d975782be">
    <lifetime type="transient"/>
  </register>
```

Comment: What is the instance mode of WCF? Is it per-call or singleton? If it is singleton, then there may be issue.

Comment: It is the default which I believe is per session, I will change this to per call to see if it has any effect

Comment: I have added the Service Behaviour attrribute to force per call behaviour and it has not helped :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't implemented a *unit of work* pattern in your application. The Unity configuration looks correct but seems that your changes aren't being committed. Look at [this blog post from the EntityFramework team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) to see how you would implement one. You should also ensure the  your implementation properly disposes of the EntityFramework context when committing the unit of work as discussed in [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366191/entity-framework-and-wcf-returning-entities-attached-to-context)